# How do I sort hash of hashes by a sub key/value using perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I would like sort the following Hash. parentXX should be sort with the value of __displayorder, the Xtopic of a parent and Xprod of a topic should sort alphabeticly.

```
$VAR1 = {
   'views' => {
      'parent23' => {
          '__displayorder' => 2,
          'vtopic1' => {
              'gprod1.1' => undef,
              'aprod1.2' => undef,
          },
          'btopic2' => {
              'tprod2.1' => undef,
              'mprod2.2' => undef,
          },
      },
      'parent98' => {
          '__displayorder' => 1,
          'atopic1' => {
              'qprod1.1' => undef,
              'jprod1.2' => undef,
          },
          'xtopic2' => {
              'kprod2.1' => undef,
              'fprod2.2' => undef,
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)%3f then have a go yourself. If you find yourself still stuck, post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a hash. Can you make do with having the names of the views in the specific order?

```
my $views = $VAR1->{views};
my @sorted_view_keys = sort {
        $views->{$a}{__displayorder} cmp $views->{$b}{__displayorder}
    } keys(%$views);
```

Or maybe you want the sorted views?

```
my @sorted_views = map { $views->{$_} } @sorted_view_keys;
   -or-
my @sorted_views = @$views[@sorted_view_keys];
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can't sort a normal Perl hash. Perl hashes are unordered. But you can use the CPAN module `Tie::IxHash` to get an ordered hash. The lines below transform all the sub-hashes from your sample output into `Tie::IxHash` hashes and do some sorting (e.g. alphabetically or by display order):

```
 use Tie::IxHash;
 my $views = $VAR1->{views};
 while(my($view_key, $view) = each %$views) {
     while(my($topic, $prods) = each %$view) {
         next if $topic =~ m{^__};
         tie my %new_prods, 'Tie::IxHash', (map { ($_ => $prods->{$_}) } sort keys %$prods);
         $view->{$topic} = \%new_prods;
     }
     tie my %new_view, 'Tie::IxHash', (map { ($_ => $view->{$_}) } sort keys %$view);
     $views->{$view_key} = \%new_view;
 }
 tie my %new_views, 'Tie::IxHash', (map { ($_ => $views->{$_}) } sort { $views->{$a}->{__displayorder} <=> $views->{$b}->{__displayorder} } keys %$views);
 $VAR1->{views} = \%new_views;
```